# use of modal 'would'

Tags: grammar

Can 'would' be used to show possibility ln the present. As-

> he would go there everyday.

Means that it is possible that he goes there everyday. Whether it is a right sentence or wrong sentence. Please clear it. I have read some sentences similar to it but unable to understand the exact translation of them. As I have read it on the internet that -

> Chennai would hope that it is only cramps.

Answer (score 1):

**Would** is not used in this way to indicate possibility.

To say:

> He would go there every day

indicates that **he used to** go there every day.

It's a construction that we use most often when reminiscing about someone, especially someone who has died/disappeared or is no longer around.

To indicate present possibility, you would say:

> He may/might go there every day.

or even

> He could go there every day

although this last statement is more likely to mean that he is/was able to go there every day.